# Using rx to modify end of word

Tags: rx

I am inserting the letter `l` for words ending in `ley`, `ily`, and `ly`.  This means that `family` would be modified to `faml`.

The code works when using the regexp string `\\(ley\\|ily\\|ly\\)\\>`, but am not getting the same result with the rx version.

```
(rx (seq word-end (or "ley" "ily" "ly")))
```

Comment: Perhaps `(seq (or "ley" "ily" "ly") word-end)` is what you need?  Have you digested the `rx` documentation?  You seem to be guessing what the right `rx` form is and then complaining here when you guess wrong.

Comment: I have but there are not any examples.  So guessing going wrong is not unheard of.

Comment: Please remove 90% of your code. The question seems to be only why your `rx` expression doesn't result in some particular string regexp. Ask that explicitly, simply.

Comment: `seq` stands for `sequence` (which you can use instead if you want): that's when you put one thing after another, but then it's important to put them in the correct order. Knowing what a sequence is leads to better guessing.

Comment: Why would you think that "list of alternatives followed by word-end" was equivalent to "word-end followed by list of alternatives"?  Did you even look at the return value of your `rx` expression to see what it was?  I don't believe you were incapable of realising this for yourself with just the barest minimum of contemplation, and I sincerely believe you are risking ending up with nobody who is willing to spend their time on your questions if you continually put in so little effort before deciding to post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to @FranBurstall's comment

There is a way to go from a regexp string to an rx expression. ie the reverse of rx

There is a package [xr](https://github.com/mattiase/xr) that is the reverse of rx.

A pretty print of the regexp

```
(xr-pp "\\(ley\\|ily\\|ly\\)\\>")
```

gives the rx as

```
(seq (group (or "ley" "ily" "ly")) eow)
```

Comment: Would your answer be preferable to `(seq (or "ley" "ily" "ly") word-end )` ?

Comment: Depends on whether you want to match the regexp rather than just test it exists. The main point is though to show xr

Answer (score 0):

As @FranBurstall mentions in a comment to the question, the problem occurred because a sequence matching a character string followed by end of word is described by `(seq "charstr" word-end)`.

The following would then fix the problem

```
(rx (seq (or "ley" "ily" "ly") word-end ))
```

Comment: Please explain in your answer what the problem was and how this fixes it. This helps others.

Comment: This is wrong: `seq` does *NOT* require `word-end` to appear at the end. *You* need to put it at the end *here* because that's what *you* want to match in *this instance*. It is *NOT* a general rule. I never downvote questions (except for spam) and I almost never downvote answers, except in the case where they are wrong: wrong answers confuse and mislead future visitors, so it is *important* that they be corrected. Please either fix this answer or delete it.

Comment: And  when you get it right, i.e. duplicate @FranBurstall's comment without adding spurious claims, it is good form to acknowledge the source: give credit where credit is due.

Comment: It would also be good for SE to not restrict me in accepting the answer!

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. You just have to wait a bit to accept it- that's all. What about the "credit where credit is due" part? Are you going to fix that?

Comment: There is no reason to make people wait and restrict them,

Comment: How can one make link to that?

Comment: Edited to add the acknowledgement - you don't need a link.

Comment: It is meant to curb your enthusiasm about accepting your own answer immediately: another, better, answer might come along which you might prefer.

Comment: I understand now.

Comment: Click on the `?` icon in the upper right of the SE window and read how it works and why some things are as they are. In this particular instance, [this section](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) explains.